# Dropbox api v2 display image probleme

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dropbox-api

Can someone help me with Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/javascript#tutorial 
I could upload an image in my app in Dropbox and I can see it in my account. but I want to know how to get a URL or the path to display it in my web application.

Thank you for help

[image]